# Move an item in illustrator to a specific location

Tags: photo, adobe-illustrator

I have created an action to move an item relatively in illustrator. This all works but I am looking for a way to move an item absolutely. So to a specific location no matter where it is.

Could anybody tell me how to do this in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

To place object in some absolute position you can use Transform Panel:

- open Transform Panel(Shift+F8)
- enter absolut position (x and y coordinates).
- to record this action do the same during recording.